# Displaying numbered list in R package

Tags: r, r-package, roxygen2

I'm having trouble getting a numbered list to display in R package help.

Here's what I have in roxygen:

```
#' @return
#' Bunch of text
#' Bunch of text: 
#'  \enumerate {
#'    \item a
#'    \item b
#'    \item c
#' }
```

This is displaying without numbers.  After I save the file, I click `Build & Reload in RStudio`, then run `devtools::document`, then `devtools::load_all`.  When I run help on the package, I get the following message in the console:

```
Using development documentation for function name
```

Comment: Is this your complete roxygen doc header because without a title I get the error message "is missing name/title. Skipping"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A simple space is causing the missing numbers: Just remove the space after `enumerate` and the first `{`.

The second issue is the **missing title doc** (which causes the documentation build to fail but I guess that is not your problem because you recognized the missing numbers so the build must have succeeded).

This will work:

```
#' My title...
#' @return
#' Bunch of text
#' Bunch of text:
#'  \enumerate{
#'    \item a
#'    \item{b}
#'    \item{c}
#' }
hello1 <- function() {
  print("Hello, world!")
}
```

`?hello1` shows then:

[image]

PS: You can recognize this kind of problem in RStudio in the build log:

> Warning: hello1.Rd:12: unexpected TEXT ' ', expecting '{'

**Edit 1:**

The name of the generated Rd file and the line number within this file is indicated in the warning after the colon (here: 12).

You find the generated Rd file in the `man` folder of the package.

Just open it and look for the line number to examine the problem:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/hello1.R
\name{hello1}
\alias{hello1}
\title{My title...}
\usage{
hello1()
}
\value{
Bunch of text
Bunch of text:
 \enumerate {         % <- this is line number 12 !!!!
   \item a
   \item{b}
   \item{c}
}
}
\description{
My title...
}
```

Comment: @R Yoda,  is there any way of telling where in the text that error is occurring?  It's not the line number there...

Comment: @matsuo_basho: See my edit in the answer on how to find the line number...